# How to use count if in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql query returns **Syntax error near '== 1**

my query is

```
SELECT COUNT( IF ( application_type== 1 ) ) as total from table_1
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT( IF ( application_type= 1, 1, 0 ) ) as total from table_1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use case when

```
SELECT COUNT(case when application_type=1 then 1 end) as total from table_1
```

OR

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total from table_1
where application_type=1
```

OR

```
SELECT count(if(application_type=1, 1, NULL)) as total from table_1
```

Comment: Can you please explain why I set **then 1** ?

Comment: @mrmithun, u've to use value or field name - you can use application_type too

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues with your syntax.  This works:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total from table_1 WHERE application_type = 1;
```

Comment: Explain him what was wrong with his syntax, so he doesn't make the same mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `if()` or `case` at all.  MySQL conveniently treats booleans as integers, so you can simply do:

```
SELECT SUM( application_type = 1 ) as total 
FROM table_1;
```

Of course, if this is all you want, then use `COUNT(*)` and move the condition to a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition IF ( application_type== 1 ) is actually returning either TRUE or FALSE which is 1 OR 0. Now if you apply COUNT on a column contains 1 OR 0, it will always return you the total ROW count of the table. So you need to adjust your query. Anyway, using SUM in place of COUNT will serve your purpose I think-

```
SELECT SUM(IF( application_type = 1)) AS total from table_1
```